# Running a busybox applet from /tmp

Tags: linux, reboot, busybox, tmpfs

There is a problematic situation with a headless Linux device.
Long story short: the rootfs gets unavailable and this blocks everything. Power recycle is the only way out and I want to automatically reboot instead manual power-cycling.

There is a `/tmp` folder, independent from the rootfs:

```
tmpfs on /tmp type tmpfs (rw,relatime)
```

So I had an idea, to copy `busybox` here, and run a script at the background:

```
# cp /bin/busybox /tmp
# (/tmp/busybox sleep 60;/tmp/busybox reboot) &
#
```

Then I raised the problematic situation to make the rootfs go down, and wait.
But no reboot happened after 60 seconds.

In spite of `/` is unavailable, doesn't this command have to reboot the device?

Answer (score 0):

One obvious problem is that the copy you create is not executable, unless you have an unusual value for `umask`. While you can use `chmod`, it is easier to use the option `-p` when copying.

```
cp -p /bin/busybox /tmp
```

There are other potential problems.

It is possible that the filesystem in /tmp doesn't allow executable files. After you create the copy, you should verify that the copy is actually executable on your system. You can use a command like `/bin/busybox echo test`.

In your situation, there are further difficulties. You want to call this when the rootfs gets unavailable. Unfortunately, `/tmp` is also mounted below the root. But access may be possible if the kernel has enough information in memory to get to `/tmp` without accessing the rootfs. It is possible that this information is in memory when you test 60 seconds later, but not after days of operation when the error occurs.

If you want to avoid the need to access `/tmp` after system failure, you can use a Bbusybox that is configured to directly call the applets, without accessing the filesystem. Then you run a script in the Busybox shell in `/tmp` that checks the condition and tries to reboot.

You may also want to look at watchdogs.

Comment: "Bbusybox that is configured to directly call the applets, without accessing the filesystem" How is this done? Watchdog is not working, HW watchdog is unavailable and the one Linux comes with, is not able to reboot the system without the rootfs.

Comment: `/tmp/busybox echo "hello"` works

Comment: Busybox calling applets directly is an option when compiling Busybox.

Comment: Thx, and "Then you run a script in the Busybox shell in /tmp": what exactly does this mean? Copying busybox to `/tmp`, and run `/tmp/busybox /tmp/my_watchdog_script.sh`?

Comment: Exactly, You copy your script and the Busybox to the tmp filesystem and hope they are still accessible when the root is gone. It would also help if you can attach a screen or serial console for your tests. Seeing error messages can be a lot faster than guessing what happens.

Comment: serial console gets blocked too once the rootfs gone. Thus as this is a headless machine, there is no way to attach any monitor to it sadly :/